# Preview text size change in Photoshop CC 2018

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, font-size

In Photoshop, since time began, when you selected text and then used the arrow keys on your keyboard you could see dynamically the text change on screen as you increased and decreased the point size. For some reason, that only the developers of Photoshop can explain, that feature has been turned off in CC 2018. Is there any way to turn that back on?

Comment: I've asked around fellow designers and for whatever reason this seems to only be affecting my Photoshop. I've thrown out my preferences and restarted and I still can't get my text to change dynamically. Annoying.

Comment: No. You have to select the font name in character panel before use the arrow keys. You are probably mistaken.

Comment: I have been having this exact problem, though it doesn't happen all the time or to all my documents. I've also noticed another bug, I'm on cc 2018, and one of my coworkers is on 2017. When she resizes text by transforming it and I have to edit the file later, the leading becomes broken. It gets stuck at "1.8 pt4" and starts getting more garbled from there. I hope Adobe fixes this nonsense soon.